# Alinhar componentes visuais

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou com dificuldades de alinhar os botoes/icones na minha activity.
 Estou usando o relative layout para posicionar os botões, mas quando compila ele fica fora de ordem.

Segue o código:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:text="@string/lbl_debitos_pendentes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lbl_debitosPendentes"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnDebitosPendentes"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnDebitosPendentes"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btnDebitosPendentes" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/lbl_dados_cadastrais"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lbl_dados_cadastrais"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnDadosCadastrais"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnDadosCadastrais"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btnDadosCadastrais" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lbl_dados_cadastrais"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/lbl_dados_cadastrais"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/lbl_dados_cadastrais"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnHistoricoPagamento"
        android:background="@drawable/historic_pgto" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/lbl_hist_pagamento"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lbl_historicoPagamento"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnHistoricoPagamento"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnHistoricoPagamento"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnHistoricoPagamento" />

    <Button

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnSolicitarAtendimento"
        android:background="@drawable/soli_atend"
        android:layout_above="@+id/lbl_historicoPagamento"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lbl_debitosPendentes"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/lbl_debitosPendentes" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/lbl_hist_atendimentos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lbl_hist_atendimento"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnHistoricoAtendimento"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnSolicitarAtendimento"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnSolicitarAtendimento" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/lbl_grafico"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button32"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button32"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button32" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/lbl_solicitar_atendimento"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lbl_solic_atendimento"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnSolicitarAtendimento"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnSolicitarAtendimento"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnSolicitarAtendimento"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="18dp" />

    <Button

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lbl_hist_atendimento"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnHistoricoAtendimento"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btnHistoricoAtendimento"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnExtratoAutenticacao"
        android:background="@drawable/extrato" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/lbl_extrato_autenticacao"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView16"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnExtratoAutenticacao"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnExtratoAutenticacao"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnExtratoAutenticacao"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/lbl_contato"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView16"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/lbl_debitosPendentes"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/lbl_debitosPendentes"
        android:id="@+id/textView17" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button32"
        android:background="@drawable/grafico"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lbl_solic_atendimento"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/lbl_solic_atendimento"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/lbl_solic_atendimento" />

    <Button

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnContato"
        tools:background="@drawable/mapa"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView17" />

    <Button

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="34dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnDadosCadastrais"
        android:background="@drawable/user_edit"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnDebitosPendentes"
        tools:ignore="RelativeOverlap,RtlHardcoded"
        tools:background="@drawable/doc_abe"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnDadosCadastrais"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnDadosCadastrais"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView16"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView16" />

    <Button

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnHistoricoAtendimento"
        tools:background="@drawable/history"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lbl_historicoPagamento"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/lbl_historicoPagamento" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Os botoes/icones devem ficar alinhados de 2 em 2.

Comment: No inicio eu sofri até usar linear layout. Este tipo de layout é simples e compatível tom versões novas e antigas. Usando no formato horizontal e vertical vai conseguir fazer tudo adaptação que deseja.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu resolvi o problema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="8">




    <Button

        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnDadosCadastrais"
        android:background="@drawable/user_edit"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
        android:layout_margin="15dp" />

    <Button

        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnDebitosPendentes"
        android:background="@drawable/doc_abe"
        android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
        android:layout_margin="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/lbl_dados_cadastrais"
        android:layout_width="87dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtDadosCadastrais"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/lbl_debitos_pendentes"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtDebitosPendentes"
        android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />

    <Button

        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnHistoricoDePagamento"
        android:background="@drawable/historic_pgto"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
        android:layout_margin="15dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnSolicitarAtendimento"
        android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
        android:background="@drawable/soli_atend"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
        android:layout_margin="15dp" />

    <TextView

        android:text="@string/lbl_hist_pagamento"
        android:layout_width="87dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtHitoricoPagamento"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/lbl_solicitar_atendimento"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtSolicitarAtendimento"
        android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />

    <Button

        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnHistoricoAtendimentos"
        android:background="@drawable/history"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
        android:layout_margin="15dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnGraficoDeUso"
        android:background="@drawable/grafico"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
        android:layout_margin="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/lbl_hist_atendimentos"
        android:layout_width="87dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtHistoricoAtendimento"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/lbl_grafico"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtGraficoDeUso"
        android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnExtratoDeAutenticacao"
        android:background="@drawable/extrato"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
        android:layout_margin="15dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"

        android:id="@+id/btnContato"
        android:background="@drawable/mapa"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
        android:layout_margin="15dp" />


    <TextView
        android:text="@string/lbl_extrato_autenticacao"
        android:layout_width="87dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtExtratoAutenticao"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/lbl_contato"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtContato"
        android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

</GridLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

O ícone seria do botão ou não? se for você pode utilizar o código abaixo:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/buttonIdDoesntMatter"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:text="buttonName"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/imageWillChange"
android:onClick="listener"
android:layout_width="fill_parent">
```

agora se for no layout você pode colocar o **LinearLayout** e setar o **layou_gravity="center"**. Porem se sua tela for ter muitos elementos isso pode pensar ao inflar a tela, ai nesse caso se você tiver muito pode ser que seja melhor usar o **ConstraintLayout** lembrando que ele ainda esta em alpha.

Comment: Sim o icone é do botão, só que estou montando uma tela de menu, tem 8 botões e vou precisar controlar por acesso de usuário. dessa forma que mandou o código não consigo resolver , tem outra forma que conhece?.@JeffersonRodriguesDosSantos.

Answer (score -1):

```
 <ImageView
   android:id="@+id/username_icon"
   android:layout_width="40dp"
   android:layout_height="40dp"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
   android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
   android:padding="3dp"
   android:src="@drawable/ic_mail_black_24dp" />

   <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
     android:layout_marginStart="4dp"

     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/username_icon"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/username_icon"
     android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/username_icon">

     <EditText
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:hint="@string/e_mail"
       android:id="@+id/editTextEmail"
       android:layout_alignTop="@+id/username_icon"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/username_icon"
       android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/username_icon"
       android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
  </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Vai ficar algo igual a isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]